# Change stroke Color to Clear Color CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgcontext

[image]I want user to draw on Custom UIView with clearcolor as stroke color. The code is working fine for other colors but not clear color.

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    context.addRect(rect)
    draw(inContext: context)
}

func draw(inContext context: CGContext) {

    context.setLineWidth(5)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
    context.setLineCap(.round)

    for line in lineArray {
        guard let firstPoint = line.first else { continue }
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: firstPoint)
        for point in line.dropFirst() {
            context.addLine(to: point)
        }
        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not working mean? What result do you desire / expect? It seems to me that your code works perfectly for drawing with clear color. I see it do exactly what I think it should do. How about you?

Comment: I have an image view and a view on top of it which is this custom view. when the user draws on the custom view.stroke color should be clear. view and image view should be visible. I am not able to do it with the above code

Comment: I don’t understand those words. Can you draw a picture of what you expect?

Comment: I have updated my question. Instead of black lines I want clear color so that i can see the image view beneath it. (imageview is already beneath it.)

Comment: Drawing with clear color does not cause anyone to "see" anything. It is the opposite: it is clear which means invisible. Again, it unclear what you expect. It sounds like you think you want to use the front view as a _mask_ that _hides_ the image view, and you want to reveal it wherever the user draws. Is that true? If so, it doesn't seem to be what you are doing.

Comment: oh! how do i achieve that?

Comment: Well, as I said, _if_ that is what you want, you want to _mask_ the image view.

Answer (score 1):

So, it sounds like you've a situation like this. You have an image being displayed in an image view:

[image]

And you want the image to be *hidden* until the user draws on top of it, at which point the user's drawing should *reveal* that part of the image, like this:

[image]

If so, what you want is not to draw with clear color; you want a *mask*. What's actually happening in that second screen shot is that we track the user's drawing and draw *black* into an otherwise clear *mask* on the image view.